# How to convert Geometry Node to Mesh?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, geometry-nodes

Hello from a Beginner,

I am actually trying to convert -right image-  Geometric Node (Donut Icing) to Mesh. But When I press " Make Instance Real ", it makes a deformed donut -left image-.

Is there a Safeway for converting Geometric Nodes to Mesh?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Most likely you need to add a [Realize Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html) node before the output

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for making this a full answer rather than a comment; I don't have the reputation yet to comment.
In addition to what [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) mentioned in his comment about adding a "Realize Instances" node, I found that "make instances real" still did not produce the desired behaviour. Instead, I found that I had to apply the "Geometry Nodes" modifier in the "Modifiers" panel, either via the dropdown or just hovering over the modifier and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to do so.

If you are using geometry nodes on a Curve instead of a Mesh, then the above might not work and you may have to do one of the following instead:

- Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in the viewport and then selecting *Visual Geometry to Mesh*.
- Using *Object > Convert > Mesh*.